# When using AES 128 CBC encryption is it possible to get NULL byte in the middle of encrypted message?

Tags: c, aes

As in the subject. I'm wondering if it is possible to get encrypted bytes like below when using AES128 CBC:

```
7b 22 63 6d 64 22 3a 22  73 65 74 41 70 22 2c 22    
73 63 6f 22 2c 22 70 61  00 73 22 3a 22 70 61 73  
73 77 6f 72 64 22 7d 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Note the NULL byte in the second row.

EDIT: A bit of background behind this question.

I have a C function that takes my buffer and plain text (utf8) after calling it I need to know who much of the buffer was filled up.

Comment: Sure. `0` is a valid value as anything else. *Any* data can be a valid AES encryption, as it should be indistinguishable from random data. And of course you can try to decrypt it and see *which* plaintext is resulting in such a ciphertext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, any byte value is possible including 0.

The implied question here is "can I use string handling functions on encrypted data".   You cannot because 0 is a valid value.  You need to keep track of the number of bytes in the encrypted data.